# DataRow conversion issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to convert system.data.datarow to an integer?

I Have a datarow which is returning the count of records which i want to store in an integer variable
The statement is as follows

```
int TotalRecords=ds.Tables[1].Rows[0];
```

here ds is the DataSet.

when i am trying to write the above statement it is telling me that i cannot implicitly convert System.Data.DataRow to int

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...also to upvote answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the value as an integer:

```
int TotalRecords = (int)ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["YourColumnName"];
```

Comment: no the same mistake it is showing "cannot convert a datarow to int"

Comment: sorry, edited to: int TotalRecords = (int)ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["YourColumnName"] where "YourColumnName" is the name of the column whose value you want.

Answer (score 0):

try that,

```
int TotalRecords=ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].Count();
```

you have to include Linq if not included

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: i included System.Linq but no definition for method "Count()"

Comment: System.Linq is not required - this is ADO.NET.